# Export from histogramdata to excel from anylogic

Tags: anylogic

at the end of my simulation I want to have some histogram dataset exported to my excel file. But now I found out that the code:

```
excelFile.writeDataSet(Histogramdata,1, 1, 1);
```

Is only supported for datasets and not for histogram data, is there another way of coding to export histogram data to excel. A loop or something which goes through the whole histogram data set and stores it in to excel?

Or is the only solution to make datasets instead of histogram data sets, but these again have the disadvantages that you can not show the mean of it in your user interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Histograms do not store the raw data. They store the count per bin and bin boundaries.

So if you need the raw data, you are better off writing it into datasets while feeding the histogram, then export to xls